# How do I get rid of a yellow/red square around my lock icon?

Tags: 2d

I am using blender for 2D animation. Several times now, on accident, I've pressed the 'i' key while my mouse was over a layer. This puts a little yellow box around the lock icon, and changes it to manual lock/unlocking. When the layer is unlocked, the box is yellow, and when it's locked, the box is red. I can no longer lock/unlock from the bottom dope sheet, and have to go to the layer tab at the right. If I click on another layer, a yellow box will automatically turn red. This makes it harder to lock and unlock the layer, as well as duplicate or edit the frames in the layer. Is there any way to get rid of this? I've tried pressing nearly every button with my mouse over the layer, and I've tried looking this up, but I can't find anything on it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The 'i' key creates a keyframe on whatever you hovered over.  This is for animation.  The intention is that there is some other frame where you change the keyframed value and then create another keyframe.  If you've created a keyframe accidentally, you can right click in the yellow field and select "delete keyframe".

Comment: I should have been more clear: my mouse wasn't in the layers tab at the bottom of the screen, but at the one all the way to the right. I think it's the 'Object Data Properties' tab? It has layers, onion skinning, vertex groups, etc. I wasn't in the tab with all the keyframes shown in it, this only has the names of the layers. My mouse was there, and over one of the names of the layers when I pressed i.